# Runtime Analysis a single for-loop with i not incrementing by 1

Tags: c++, runtime

```
double sum_skip7 (double array[], int n)  
    //n: size of the array. Assume n is divisible by 7    
{  
    double sum = 0;  
    for(int i=0; i< n; i=i+7)  
        sum = sum + array[i];  

    return sum;
}
```

I understand that if the for-loop is to increment `i` by one, the number of times it takes to run the for-loop statement is `n+1` (`i`= 0,1,2,...`n`). But since `i` is being incremented by `7` will it still be `n+1` times? Or will it be `(n-7)+1` times? The second answer seems to make more sense but I am not willing to bet on it.

Comment: It's being incremented by 7, not 1. So no, it will not be n+1.

Comment: It only takes n because you have < , so  is 0,1,2... (n-1) . If you increment by 7 it only takes n/7  but in that case you're just adding the elements that meets  i%7==0

Answer (score 2):

No, it's n/7, because i is incremented by 7 each time.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Wouldn't it be (n/7) +1 since the it will check one last time before breaking out of the for loop?

Comment: The conditional `i < n` will be run `(n/7) + 1` times. The code inside the for loop however `n/7` times

Answer (score 0):

Since i is going up by 7 each time we can see that the loop will run n/7 times. Since with run times we ignore constants this has a runtime of O(n).